# Kibana - Importing visualisation errors

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have exported a visualisation in `Kibana`, using the export button under settings. This has given me a `JSON` file. The name of the visualisation is Transaction-count.

I have then deleted the visualisation from `Kibana`.

I would now like to import the visualisation back into `Kibana` using the API.

If I type 
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/Transaction-count" -d I get the following error;

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed
>   to parse"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to
>   parse","caused_by":{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor
>   detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed
>   xcontent bytes"}}

If I manually import the visualisation via the web GUI, it works fine.

If I then type;
curl XGET "http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/Transaction-count" it gives me the following JSON;

```
{"index":".kibana","type":"visualization","id":"Transaction-count","version":1,"found":true,"_source":{"title":"Transaction count","visState":"{\"title\":\"Transaction count\",\"type\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"handleNoResults\":true,\"fontSize\":\"120\"},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"count\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{}}],\"listeners\":{}}","uiStateJSON":"{}","description":"","savedSearchId":"Transactions","version":1,"kibanaSavedObjectMeta":{"searchSourceJSON":"{\"filter\":[]}"}}}
```

If I then type;

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/Transaction-count" -d '{"index":".kibana","type":"visualization","id":"Transaction-count","version":1,"found":true,"_source":{"title":"Transaction count","visState":"{\"title\":\"Transaction count\",\"type\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"handleNoResults\":true,\"fontSize\":\"120\"},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"count\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{}}],\"listeners\":{}}","uiStateJSON":"{}","description":"","savedSearchId":"Transactions","version":1,"kibanaSavedObjectMeta":{"searchSourceJSON":"{\"filter\":[]}"}}}'
```

I receive the following output;

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Field
>   [_index] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document.
>   Use the index API request
>   parameters."}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Field
>   [_index] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document.
>   Use the index API request parameters."},"status":400}

Running version 2.3.3 of `Elastic` and 4.5.1 of `Kibana`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You said that you delete the visualisation, so if you type "http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/Transaction-count"  it's make sense to get error

Comment: Hi there,This was after manually importing the visualisation via the UI